# Python string argument without an encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-unicode

Am trying to a run this piece of code, and it keeps giving an error saying "String argument without an encoding"

```
ota_packet = ota_packet.encode('utf-8') + bytearray(content[current_pos:(final_pos)]) + '\0'.encode('utf-8')
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you want to get: `(ota_packet + content[current_pos:final_pos] + '\0').encode('utf-8')`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are passing in a string object to a `bytearray()`:

```
bytearray(content[current_pos:(final_pos)])
```

You'll need to supply an encoding argument (second argument) so that it can be encoded to bytes.

For example, you could encode it to UTF-8:

```
bytearray(content[current_pos:(final_pos)], 'utf8')
```

From the [`bytearray()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray):

> The optional *source* parameter can be used to initialize the array in a few different ways:
>
> - If it is a string, you must also give the *encoding* (and optionally, *errors*) parameters; `bytearray()` then converts the string to bytes using `str.encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
byteObject = b'\x18,\xa3\xf0A\x93*<bAd\x15K.A\xba'
print(byteObject)
print('-----------asbytearray----------')

print('-------As a string------------------')
o = base64.b64encode(bytes(str(byteObject), 'utf-8'))
print(o.decode("utf-8"))`enter code here`
print('--------Nonce as a string------------------')
```