# "TypeError: string argument without an encoding", but the string is encoded?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I am working on converting an [existing program](https://github.com/kabniel/last2libre/blob/master/scrobble.py#L34) from Python2 to Python3. One of the methods in the program authenticates the user with a remote server. It will prompt the user to enter in a password.

```
def _handshake(self):
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    token = (md5hash(md5hash((self.password).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                + str(bytes('timestamp').encode('utf-8'))))
    auth_url = "%s/?hs=true&p=1.2&u=%s&t=%d&a=%s&c=%s" % (self.name,
                                                          self.username,
                                                          timestamp,
                                                          token,
                                                          self.client_code)
    response = urlopen(auth_url).read()
    lines = response.split("\n")
    if lines[0] != "OK":
        raise ScrobbleException("Server returned: %s" % (response,))
    self.session_id = lines[1]
    self.submit_url = lines[3]
```

The problem with this method is that after the integer is converted to a string, it needs to be encoded. But as far as I can tell, it is already encoded? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161243/python-string-argument-without-an-encoding) but I was having a hard time applying that to the context of this program.

This is the line giving me problems.

- `+ str(bytes('timestamp').encode('utf-8'))))`

  - `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`

I have tried playing around with alternate ways of doing this, all with varying types of errors.

- `+ str(bytes('timestamp', 'utf-8'))))`

  - `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`
- `+ str('timestamp', 'utf-8')))`

  - `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

I'm still getting started learning Python (but I have beginner to intermediate knowledge of Java), so I am not completely familiar with the language yet. Does anyone have any thoughts on what this issue might be?

Thanks!

Comment: I notice the code in the link has changed that line to `+ str(timestamp)).hexdigest())` is that possibly what needs to be done?

Comment: `str(bytes('timestamp').encode('utf-8'))` - what the heck? What were you trying to do there?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Originally, it was, but when I was trying to run the script (e.g. `+ str(b'timestamp').hexdigest()))`), I received a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'` in return. It might be, but I'm not quite sure on this one.

Comment: @user2357112 I've been trying all kinds of combinations to get this line right, it's gone through many forms today... ultimately, I'm trying to just get this integer to convert to a format that Py3 will take as valid.

Comment: do you understand that `timestamp` is a name, `'timestamp'` is a string literal (no relation to the `timestamp` name)? You don't need bytes here. To convert an integer to a string in Python: `str(timestamp)`. Use `urllib.parse.urlencode()` to create the query. Pass it `str` objects (Unicode in Python). You might need to call `.decode('ascii', 'strict')` on a `.hexdigest()` result, to get `str` instead of `bytes`.

Answer (score 12):

This error is due to how you create bytes in python 3.

You will not do `bytes("bla bla")` but just `b"blabla"` or you need to specify an encoding type like `bytes("bla bla","utf-8")` because it needs to know what was the original encoding before turning it into an array of numbers.

Then the error

```
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Should disappear.

You have either bytes or str. If you have a bytes value and you want to turn it in str you should do:

```
my_bytes_value.decode("utf-8")
```

And it will return you a str.

I hoped it help ! Have a nice day !

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! So, I first tried rewriting it just as `b'timestamp'`, but this gave me `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`. Instead, I tried doing `str(b'timestamp')`, but this outputs `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`. Your explanation makes sense, but I'm just having a hard time figuring out to return the value as a string. I tried using a `decode("utf-8")` but to no avail. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: do `bytes('timestamp','utf-8')`

Comment: Now I'm getting `TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`