# python 3 string argument without an encoding

Tags: python, string

This code worked with Python 2.7 but on Python 3.4 I get "string argument without an encoding" error

```
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(bytes('Someuser:Somepassword')).encode('ascii')}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bytes encoding python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161243/python-string-argument-without-an-encoding)

Comment: Use `b'Someuser:Somepassword'` if this is a hardcoded literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(bytes('Someuser:Somepassword','ascii')).decode('ascii')}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `bytes()` class constructor now expects the encoding as second param. Example:

```
bytes("mystring", "ascii")
```